# Не удается запустить коллекцию тестов в jenkins

Tags: jenkins

НУ в двух словах дела обстоят так, есть коллекция тестов в Postman, на компе с помощью newman все запускается норм, а вот решил попробовать в jenkins и тут бедуля.
вот запрос в execute shell **/usr/local/bin/newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/38a1ac261075b1d3d809** так же пробовал без /usr/local/bin/ результат тот же.
В логе следующая ошибка, а точнее их целая кучища:

```html
FATAL: Failed to load the key: hudson.console.ConsoleNote.MAC
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/hudson.console.ConsoleNote.MAC
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
    at jenkins.security.DefaultConfidentialStore.store(DefaultConfidentialStore.java:79)
    at jenkins.security.ConfidentialKey.store(ConfidentialKey.java:52)
    at jenkins.security.HMACConfidentialKey.getKey(HMACConfidentialKey.java:132)
Caused: java.lang.Error: Failed to load the key: hudson.console.ConsoleNote.MAC
    at jenkins.security.HMACConfidentialKey.getKey(HMACConfidentialKey.java:136)
    at jenkins.security.HMACConfidentialKey.createMac(HMACConfidentialKey.java:115)
    at jenkins.security.HMACConfidentialKey.mac(HMACConfidentialKey.java:74)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleNote.encodeToBytes(ConsoleNote.java:209)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleNote.encode(ConsoleNote.java:224)
    at hudson.console.HyperlinkNote.encodeTo(HyperlinkNote.java:94)
    at hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote.encodeTo(ModelHyperlinkNote.java:65)
    at hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote.encodeTo(ModelHyperlinkNote.java:33)
    at hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote.encodeTo(ModelHyperlinkNote.java:29)
    at hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause.print(Cause.java:457)
    at hudson.model.BuildListener.started(BuildListener.java:49)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1862)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Прошу помощи, возможно была у кого-нибудь похожая беда

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка же понятна, Jenkins не может открыть файл:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/hudson.console.ConsoleNote.MAC
```

Проверьте права на чтение/запись по указанному пути для пользователя `jenkins`.